# Centos 7 - SSL without virtual host

Tags: centos, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

so after many many hours I somehow manage to repair/reinstall whole VPS, sweting my blood literally.

Now last step setting up SSL - ultra cautious, because I think, last time here I manage to fk up, with virtual host and etc. It´s my first time working with server so google is my dev/debug/etc but now  I´m too afraid to go by those steps.

So I Woud like to ask more experience users, how to set up SSl [without virtual host].

Many thanks!!

Michael

Comment: The configs between SSL in vhost and 'global' SSL config is very much the same. I. Which OS and web server application are you using? Assuming cause of the use of 'vhost' you're using Apache?

Comment: In the end i went for virtualhost and setup it thanks to this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-centos-7

Answer (score 1):

The [Applied Crypto Hardening](https://bettercrypto.org/) guide gives you secure sample  configurations for all common webservers.

For *Apache* [it suggests](https://bettercrypto.org/#_apache) the following in the vhost configuration:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
#SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt
#SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCompression off

Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"      
# Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=15768000 ; includeSubDomains" 

Header always set Public-Key-Pins "pin-sha256=\"YOUR_HASH=\"; pin-sha256=\"YOUR_BACKUP_HASH=\"; max-age=7776000; report-uri=\"https://YOUR.REPORT.URL\"" 
SSLCipherSuite 'EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!IDEA:!ECDSA:kEDH:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA'
```

The suggested [nginx settings](https://bettercrypto.org/#_nginx) are:

```
ssl on;
ssl_certificate cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key cert.key;

ssl_session_timeout 5m;

ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # not possible to do exclusive
ssl_ciphers 'EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!IDEA:!ECDSA:kEDH:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA';
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"; # six months
# add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains";
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The OP did not state which server software he is actually using, so copying any configuration snippets here would just be guessing.
I consider this very broad answer applicable for this question, since it should include what the OP wants.

Comment: It also becomes completely useless when that link dies. That's why link only answers are not really welcome here.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I copied the configurations for the two most common webservers into my answer.